# MongoDB Atlass can't connect via Mongo Compass on Mac - Get Error queryTxt ESERVFAIL

Tags: mongodb

Wondered if anyone knows how to fix my connection to a mongo db database hosted on mongo atlas.

Trying to connect to it by mongo compass, followed instructions to connect to compass found within the cluster on Atlas but get this message in the yellow box when I try to connect:

```
queryTxt ESERVFAIL
```

Does anyone know what it means? How to fix?

Comment: This is on windows - not sure how good it is to do this :: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zu4StZkyYYc , but seems like it does work !! By this at least if you get an idea on what the issue is then at least you can try other approaches on windows or on Mac how to fix this !!

Comment: I've watched that and tried turning off my virus protection and still doesn't seem to make a difference. Unless I am missing some as I am on Mac and video is a windows users.

Comment: Can you show how you are trying to connect?